# css content: X symbol

Tags: css

i was just looking though some css code on todomvc and i wanted to know how they did their destroy button. I found an X symbol.
i'm relative new to programming and i'm curious what is that? how do you make something like that?

and here is a screenshot:

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>
[image]

Comment: @Pumbaa80 That's a Heavy Ballot X. The screenshot shows a Heavy Multiplication X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Windows Key + R</kbd>, type `charmap` and hit Run.

You can now happily explore all of the characters in all of the fonts on your system, choose one, then copy-paste it to your code.

However, I would advise against just blindly copying. I'm a single-byte-character-set-nerd, so I would prefer to use `\2716` instead of directly pasting ✖ into my CSS file. You can find the code by clicking the desired character and looking for the `U+####` in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a Unicode character that you can type (or paste) into text just like any other. As long as the browser knows how to interpret the CSS file encoding (which it does) and the character is acceptable as part of the input (which it is for CSS) then it is no different to use than any plain English letter.

We can't tell which one exactly from the screenshot, but you can see some likely options [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark).

Answer (score 0):

They did it using generated content in CSS, which means that when CSS is disabled, the symbol does not appear there at all. In the CSS rule for generated content, the symbol has been inserted as such, which looks odd, since it should be in quotes, but you are actually showing us just a look at the document via developer tools in some browser, and such tools are known to simplify and modify things. It is not possible to deduce from the given data how they entered the character.

Independently of the way in which the symbol has been entered, it will not display at all in many browsing situations, since [font support to HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2716/fontsupport.htm) (which is what the symbol seems to be) is limited. It would be much safer to use an image.